# writing a loop to go into subdirectory folders and then to copy and relabel folder names in unix

Tags: unix

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I am having problems writing a loop that goes into a directory with multiple folders and copies and
relabels the name of each folder. Each of the folders is labelled in the same way to start, followed by different numbers, 
so the structure is:

```
groupfolder1  
   123456789_ab_1234  
   123456789_ab_1235  
   123456789_ab_1236  
   123456789_ab_1237  

groupfolder2  
   123456789_cd_1310  
   123456789_cd_1321    
   123456789_cd_1322  
   123456789_cd_1323
```

I want to go into each groupfolder (e.g., 123456789_ab_1234) and make a new folder with the same contents but labelled (e.g., sub-1234).

I have trying to learn Unix but am struggling with moving from completing abstract exercises to real-life problems so really appreciate responses and any explanations of how you came to a solution.

Regards E

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand you want something like

```
for d in *
do
  if test -d $d
  then
    mkdir /tmp/sub-$d
    (cd $d ; tar cf - .) | (cd /tmp/sub-$d ; tar xf -)
    mv /tmp/sub-$d $d/.
  fi
done
```

Above I suppose you are already in groupfolder1 for instance

I don't know how are all your directories, may be you can add an embedding loop to start on the parent level containing groupfolder1 / groupfolder2 etc an go into them automatically like that :

```
for dd in *
do
  if test -d $dd
  then
    cd $dd
    for d in *
    do
      if test -d $d
      then
        mkdir /tmp/sub-$d
        (cd $d ; tar cf - .) | (cd /tmp/sub-$d ; tar xf -)
        mv /tmp/sub-$d $d/.
      fi
    done 
    cd ..
  fi
done
```

Comment: Dear Bruno, thank you for the reply. Its most appreciated. For your first code. 
To check, what does the line 'test -d $d' mean.
Is the line '(cd $d ; tar cf - .) | (cd /tmp/sub-$d ; tar xf -)' optional?

Comment: @Eunice  `test -d $d` checks $d is a directory, the `for d in *` will iterate on all elements so also files

Comment: @Eunice  `(cd $d ; tar cf - .) | (cd /tmp/sub-$d ; tar xf -)` cannot be optional, this is the line doing the copy you request

Answer (score 0):

woops posted this in the wrong section. Thank you the explanation.

I tried this: 
cd /media/Eunice/'Drive B'/groupfolder1/
for d in *
do
  if test -d $d
  then
    mkdir /tmp/sub-$d
    (cd $d ; tar cf - .) | (cd /tmp/sub-$d ; tar xf -)
    mv /tmp/sub-$d $d/.
  fi
done

And received this error.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/sub-123456789_ab_1234’: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: /tmp/sub-123456789_ab_1234: No such file or directory

My concern is that 'd' here refers to the folder '123456789_ab_1234' and for the purposes of making a new folder, I need to take the numbers after '123456789_ab_' to make the label for the new folder such as sub-1234. Is there a way to easily identify 'd' as '1234'